# symfony 2.1 phpunit Swift_Message class not found

Tags: symfony, phpunit, swiftmailer, classnotfound

I've an issue with symfony and phpunit. Our peoject is growing bigger and bigger. So we decided to activate process isolation for phpunit because the server couldn't stand the amount of tests anymore (Not enough RAM). Since then all test which send mails aren't working anymore. Could someone please help us? The test below works perfectly fine if processIsolation="false" but it fails if processIsolation="true"

Versions:

- symfony 2.1.8-dev
- phpunit 3.7.9

**ERROR Message**

Project\AppBundle\Tests\MailTest::testSendMail
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Swift_Message' not found in /var/www/project/src/Project/AppBundle/Tests/MailTest.php

**Test**

```
public function testSendMail()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message->setFrom('example@example.com')
        ->setTo('example@example.com')
        ->setSubject('Subject')
        ->setBody('Hello World')
        ->setContentType('text/html');

    $client->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

**phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    bootstrap="./autoload.php"
    processIsolation="true"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    syntaxCheck="false" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/Project/AppBundle/Tests/MailTest.php</directory>
        </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: How do you run your tests? Ensure that you tell phpunit where phpunit.xml config file is with "-c" option. So if it is in "app" directory it should look like this: "phpunit -c app src/Project/AppBundle/Tests/MailTest.php"

Comment: Yes this is the exact command I us to run it. but still not working.

Comment: Try change: bootstrap="./autoload.php" with bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused because Switfmailer defines a constant
SWIFT_REQUIRED_LOADED after it installs it's autoloader. The
autoloader checks this constant, and if it's already defined, refuses
to install the autoloader. In process isolation, PHPUnit ensures that
all defined constants are re-defined in the processs that gets spawned
to run the test. Unfortunately, this means that SWIFT_REQUIRED_LOADED
is defined in the test process, so the autoloader doesn't load (see
"swift_required.php" in the swiftmailer source directory). Note that
if you turn off include global state for the test via annotations your
tests still won't work, because the bootstrap file is passed to the
test process via the __PHPUNIT_BOOTSTRAP global variable (see
TestCaseMethod.tpl in the PHPUnit directory). Without the globals,
this global is undefined in the test process and the bootstrap file is
not included breaking the tests.

The only work around that I found that works was to replace the line
`$constants = PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState::getConstantsAsString();`
with
`$constants = '';`
in the run method of TestCase.php in the PHPUnit source distribution. If your code
relies on global constants to be defined before your test cases run 
this fix obviously won't work for you (class constants are a
 different story); unless said constants will be redefined safely in the 
course of running your test cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a problem related to the swiftmailer autoloader.

I encountered the same problem and fixed it in a forked repository of swiftmailer.

Here you can find the PR for the fix: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/pull/416.

<strike>If you do not wish to wait until this is merged you can use my repository by adding this to your `composer.json`.</strike>

```
"require": {
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "dev-master as 5.0.x-dev"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "https://github.com/NickStemerdink/swiftmailer.git"
    }
]
```

**UPDATE:** The PR has been merged in the meanwhile, so you can just update to the latest swiftmailer version.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you first instantiate $message and call static::createClient afterwards?